# SQL execution returns different results than execution directly in MS SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have quite confusion with SQL, so maybe I am doing something wrong.

I was trying to build a query which will display results from several SELECT's. The code is very simple, but in general it goes like this:

***with results into sql text  option***

```
select  MessageId from   NsDelivery..NudgeResponseDump (NOLOCK) where Pk_RowId = 28901649
```

output

```
0:1550774328341685 9d012f009d012f
```

***with out results into sql text  option***

```
    select  MessageId from   NsDelivery..NudgeResponseDump (NOLOCK) where Pk_RowId = 28901649
```

output

```
0:1550774328341685
```

I dont know why string data is missing in second option please give me valid explanation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing there's a null-character (aka null terminator) between the two parts of the string (not `NULL` value, but `CHAR(0)`). This character causes the string to be cut off in results to grid mode. There's some information [here](http://www.datainsights.nl/blog-technique/odd-character-handling-null/).
Essentially, the last part of the string is there, but in the visualization it is cut off due to the null-character. You can test it by casting the string to a `VARBINARY`, a null-character will show up as `00`.